# Why I cannot import a function from a class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's a file named "importable" where I try to import the method test function.

```
class SoonImported:
   def __init__(self, x):
       self.x = x

   def methodTest(self):
       print(self.x)
```

In another file I have this line of code that cannot be changed (because my example is based on a homework).

```
from importable import SoonImported, methodTest
```

When I try to run this script it gives me an Import error and says that it "cannot import name 'methodtest'". How should I correct the soonImported class in order to make it work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would even want to import a method? You have to create a `SoonImported` instance before you can use the method anyway. Importing a method wouldn't achieve anything useful.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Methods are properties of the class and of the class instances. If you import the class, the methods are included.

Comment: How is methodTest called in the file you aren't allowed to edit? I think this will help us know how it should be defined. Is it called as methodTest() or methodTest(something)? The self object is passed automatically to a method inside a class, but not for a general function definition.

Comment: methodTest is just called in a file that I cannot edit. We write the code and then copy paste it to a page where it is tested. That's just how it is and I can do nothing to change it. But methodTest is called in original assignment methodTest(stringname). But that happens only after it is imported.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `methodTest` is defined inside of `SoonImported`. So it would be addressed like this `from importable import SoonImported` and then `methodTest` would be called like

```
instance = SoonImported()
instance.methodTest()
```

Comment: Cannot do that. I can change only the soonImported class (and the file where it is). It is a homework.

Comment: @mrSimple If you can only change the class, why do you need to import it?

Comment: @mrSimple It literally isn't possible to import a method. Either you misunderstood the homework assignment, or the homework assignment is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't import a method from a class without the rest of the class because the method only exists within the context of the class. Think of importing like borrowing. You want to borrow a lawn mower from your friend. Except that what you have there is like trying to borrow a lawn mower from your friend without making friends with anybody first. If you don't have any friends, how can you expect to borrow lawn mowers from anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your homework is correctly written, it seems likely that the methodTest should be a function rather than a method of the SoonImported class. I'm guessing in the second file you have lines somewhere of something similar to:

```
SoonImported_object = SoonImported("Some Text")
methodTest(SoonImported_object)
```

If this is the case, then methodTest is not a method, but a function and should be defined as something like the following;

```
class SoonImported:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

def methodTest(SoonImported_object):
    print(SoonImported_object.x)
```

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Just import the class and use it like your normally would

*importable.py*

```
class SoonImported:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def method_test(self):
        print(self.x)
```

*vash.py*

```
from importable import SoonImported

a = SoonImported(1)
a.method_test()
```

> ```
> python3.7 vash.py
> 1
> ```