# Understanding usage of methods of datetime class from datetime module without making an instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, oop, module

However, I was doing my own Python practice using the datetime module and got confused with the below line `datetime.now()`.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
```

I know that `datetime` is a class and `now()` is a method but what I am confused about is that should we not use an object to call the method? Or is it a `static`/`class` method which is usually called by `classname.method`?

I tried to mimic the same by creating a module, class and tried calling it from another module so that I can only import object of the class in another module and call the methods like `object.method()` but I am unable to import object in another module.

I have two python files myclass.py and main.py and both are in same directory.

```
# myclass.py

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, brand):
        self.brand = brand

    def my_car(self):
        print(f'this is {self.brand} new car')

 my_obj = MyClass("BMW")
```

Now from main.py

```
# main.py

from myclass import my_obj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_obj.my_car()
```

1. Can someone please guide me how `datetime.now()` is being called? Is it being called using class method approach (`class.method`) or is it being called using datetime object (`object.method`). I am just curious and trying to understand the concept behind it.
2. Is it possible to import only object from another module? I read couple of links on stackoverflow which are as following but I am confused:

   [Instance a Python object from another Python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777921/instance-a-python-object-from-another-python-file)

   [Why I cannot import a function from a class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631246/why-i-cannot-import-a-function-from-a-class-in-python)

I am really curious and want to know the concept. Is my understanding correct or not?

Comment: You should look into how modules are "called". What you need is some way to ascertain that you are infact in the right directory and can do things like `from .module import my_method`. One way to do that is via `__file__`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do) for what this does. This will likely help explain what is going on with your code.

Answer (score 3):

`datetime.now()` is a classmethod.

Your import doesn't work because of this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_obj = MyClass("BMW")
    my_obj.my_car()
```

The entire purpose of the if statement is to determine if the module is being imported, or is being executed directly.

If the module is being imported, `__name__` is *not* equal to `"__main__"`, and thus `my_obj` does not exist.

Comment: I have removed __name__=='__main__' from myclass.py. I have added __name__=='__main__': and created my_obj.my_car() in main.py. It is working fine now. Could you please check in my question section (I have modified) if it's fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [datetime source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/54b5e4da8a4c6ae527ab238fcd6b9ba0a3ed0fc7/Lib/datetime.py#L1695):

```py
class datetime(date):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def now(cls, tz=None):
        "Construct a datetime from time.time() and optional time zone info."
        t = _time.time()
        return cls.fromtimestamp(t, tz)
```

The [`@classmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) creates a class method. It implicitly passes the class as a first argument.

This approach is often used as an alternative constructor such as

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, brand):
        self.brand = brand

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        return cls(d["brand"])  # or cls(**d)
```

```py
from cars import Car

car_description = {"brand": "DeLorean"}

car = Car.from_dict(car_description)
```

**Note:** The class method has no `self` reference. In this example, the class hasn't even been instantiated yet.